How to implement Google ReCaptcha for MacOS?
I am using the Google reCaptcha in iOS and android native apps, which is working fine. But I also want to implement the Google ReCaptcha in MacOS app as well. Google ReCaptcha Enterprise dose not offer any lib or SDK for MacOS. So I was trying to use the Google ReCaptcha in WebView in MacOS using java Script code.
But I am always getting the error : "ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key", when loading that page in Web view in MacOS app.
I am using below code for implementing it
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=MY_KEY"></script>
    <script>
        function onSubmit() {
                grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(function() {
                    grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('MY_KEY', {action: 'LOGIN'}).then(function(token) {
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.recaptchaCallback.postMessage(token);
                    });
                });
            }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="onSubmit()">Verify</button>
</body>

</html>

I also tried turning off the Domain Verification from captcha key setting for the Key that I am using.
When Domain Verification tuned off, this same code worked fine when I tried in online html compiler in browser, but not in MacOS.
Any idea why Google ReCaptcha is not working when loaded using java script in MacOS's webview ?
Also please let me know if there is any other way to implement Google ReCaptcha in MacOS App ?
Thanks.
